# How to update system image of google nexus 7 (Razorg) to android L

Tags: google-play, android-5.0-lollipop, nexus-7

I don't know i am asking in right place , If i am wrong please guide me where to ask this.

I have google nexus 7(Razorg)LTE  want to update the OS of that device to Android L.
But in developer preview they released android L Image only for Nexuse 7(Razor) Wifi.
Can any one guide me to solve this issues.

Answer (score 1):

There are no images of Android L for Nexus 7 LTE (razorg) yet.
So you cant update it. Images for Nexus 7 wifi (razor) and Nexus 5 are development preview. Updates for your device will be available after release.
Btw i have the same model.